# To find the smallest integer greater than $23$ with certain modular residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> The question asks to find the smallest integer greater than $23$ that leaves the remainders $2,3,2$ when divided by $3,5,7$ respectively. The answer is given as $128$.

I used C.R.T. to solve this.  $$x\equiv2\pmod 3\\ x\equiv3\pmod 5\\ x\equiv2\pmod 7
$$
where $M=m_1·m_2·m_3=3×5×7=105$.

From here I get solutions, $$x\equiv2\pmod 3\\ x\equiv1\pmod 5\\ x\equiv1\pmod 7$$
After that I find\begin{align*}
x &\equiv 2×2×5×7+1×3×3×7+1×2×3×5\\ &\equiv 140+63+30\\ &\equiv 233 \pmod{105},
\end{align*}  where I again find that $x=23$.

But one thing I have noticed that $233=105×1+128$. I cannot continue from here. 
I need help and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The "From here I get solutions..." is incomprehensible for me: how applying the CRT gives you those "solutions" and not the final one, which is unique modulo $\;3\cdot5\cdot7=105\;$ ?

Comment: @thevbm The solutions are actually given by $23+105n$. Since substituting in $n=0$ gives $23$, you can substitute the next $n$ which is $n=1$.

Comment: You could just observe that $23$ itself has the correct remainders modulo $3,5$ and $7$. By CRT the solutions form a single residue class modulo $3\cdot5\cdot7=105$, and you already know which class it is! So....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying directly [the following proof](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/) of CRT, for example:

$$\begin{cases}y_1=\frac{105}3=35\;\implies y_1=2\pmod3\implies y_1^{-1}=2\pmod3\\{}\\y_2=\frac{105}5=21\implies y_2=1\pmod5\implies y_2^{-1}=1\pmod5\;\\{}\\y_3=\frac{105}7=15\implies y_3=1\pmod7\implies y_3^{-1}=1\pmod7\end{cases}$$

so that

$$2\cdot35\cdot2+3\cdot21\cdot1+2\cdot15\cdot1=233\;\;\text{ is a solution, and}$$

$$233=128\pmod{105}\;\;\text{is another solution, and}$$

$$128=23\pmod105\;\;\text{ is the unique solution modulo}\;105$$

Observe that unless you consider things modulo $\;3\cdot5\cdot7=105\;$ at the end , there is not "the" solution, but only one out of infinitely many

Comment: Yes, now I understand and thank you for providing the link.

Comment: Following the link you provided, one question I have (from an example given there) to make my doubt clear. suppose system of congruences is given as $x\equiv 5 \mod 6$ $x\equiv 3 \mod 8$. Here g..c.d of the moduli is $2$. The first congruence implies $x\equiv 1\mod 2$, also the second congruence implies $x\equiv 1\mod 2$Now to reduce the system of congruency to a simpler form if we divide the g.c.d of the moduli from the modulud of the first congruence, then how is it $x\equiv2 \mod3$? rather it should be $x\equiv 1 \mod 3$. If I'm wrong, please correct me. Thank you

Comment: @thevbm I'm not sure what your doubt *exactly* is, but remember the CRT applies for **coprime** moduli, so reducing your moduli as you did can help...but then you should be careful when going back to the original ones.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\equiv y \equiv 2 \mod 3,$ and $x\equiv y \equiv 3 \mod  5,$ and $x\equiv y \equiv 2 \mod 7.$ Then  $x-y \equiv 0$ modulo $3,5,$ and $7.$

So $x-y$ is divisible by $3,5,$ and $7,$ so $x-y$ is divisible by $(3)(5)(7)=105.$  So if $y=23$ and $x>y$ then $x=23+105n$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$

And if $x=23+105n$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ then $x\equiv 23$ modulo $3,5, $ and $7.$